# CRM Plugin get Title of a page in C#

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2013

I am creating a Plugin for CRM Which sets the Title of the page as First Name for Account Entity.

The desired result I have achieved the same by writing a **javascript function on formload Event** 
in CRM.

Following is the code

```
var titlename = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("firstname").getValue();  
    var titleSpan = document.getElementById('form_title_div');  
     if(titleSpan) {  
        for(var i = 0;i < titleSpan.children.length;i++) {  
               if(titleSpan.children[i].className == 'ms-crm-Form-Title-Data autoellipsis') {  
                titleSpan.children[i].innerText = titlename;  
                 }  
          }  
     }
```

But my client don't want any javascript code instead he wants it thru **Plugin**.

I have written a plugin but don't know how to get and set the Title of the page.

**Plugin project is a C# Class library**.

Code is below for **Plugin**

**Basically I want C# code for commented(Javascipt) Lines**

```
using (var crm = new XrmServiceContext(service))  
{  
                var account = crm.ContactSet.Where(c => c.AccountId == id).First();  
                var titlename = contact.Crmp_Firstname.ToString();  
                //var titleSpan = document.getElementById('form_title_div');  
                //if(titleSpan) {  
                    //for(var i = 0;i < titleSpan.children.length;i++) {  
                        //if(titleSpan.children[i].className == 'ms-crm-Form-Title-Data autoellipsis') {  
                            //titleSpan.children[i].innerText = titlename;  
               //}  
          //}  
     //}  
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Accessing the DOM is unsupported and generally a bad idea; the code may break at any time. You could place the info that you need in the form header instead; it may even be more visible to the user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to modify the title of an account form by a plugin.
This because plugins act server side, instead JavaScript (and your account form) is executed client side.
CRM doesn't store the title of the account, but generates it at runtime.

Comment: is 100% correct - this is technically not possible since there is no value to set. I would also point out that your client's requirement has no logical basis since the CRM form itself already makes extensive use of JavaScript.